# Crystal Reports 9 making new connection to ODBC Simba Client

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, windows-xp, odbc, trace

Hi I'm using Crystal Reports 9 and I'm trying to create a new connection with an ODBC server Simba Client.  When I try to do this, CR9 freezes and gives me a crw9.exe error that needs to shut it down.  I did a trace then and found some errors which I am not quite sure what to do with.  I will post the error messages below that I think are important and explain them.

So the trace goes well for while and then this happens:

```
crw32           1364-1030   EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 1 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    HDBC                027B2040
    HWND                00BB0AEA
    WCHAR *             0x74329110 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x74329110 
    SWORD                        2 
    SWORD *             0x00000000
    UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

    DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr). (0)
```

Then it goes on for a little more and a few more lines down we get this one:

```
crw32           1364-1030   EXIT  SQLGetInfoW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
    HDBC                027B2040
    UWORD                    10003 <SQL_CATALOG_NAME>
    PTR                 0x0012C4F4 
    SWORD                       40 
    SWORD *             0x0012C4F0

    DIAG [HYC00] [Simba][SimbaClient ODBC Driver][SimbaLNA][Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver]Driver not capable. (0)
```

This last error comes up a few more times until I decide to stop the trace.  Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 0):

The first warning on connection is from Crystal Reports trying to set the ODBC version to 3, however the ODBC client you're using only supports ODBC 2. The warning is informational and is unlikely to cause your problem.

The second error when CR9 is trying to get the SQL_CATALOG_NAME is because the SimbaClient ODBC Driver in use here does not support this attribute. I'm unsure of the database that you're connecting to with your SimbaClient ODBC driver, however you should contact the vendor of the database to see if they have an updated version of their software which supports ODBC 3.